# Getting xml elements by tag name

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I have seen almost all questions here regarding this issue but none is related.

```
$employees = simplexml_load_string($response)->c->q[1]['v'];
```

**$employees = SimpleXML Object:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "Articles_Schema.xsd" >
    <row id="1">
        <EmployeeID>
            <![CDATA[123]]>
        </EmployeeID>
        <EmplopyeeName>
            <![CDATA[John Doe]]>
        </EmplopyeeName>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
       <EmployeeID>
            <![CDATA[456]]>
        </EmployeeID>
        <EmplopyeeName>
            <![CDATA[Jack Mill]]>
        </EmplopyeeName>
    </row>
</rows>
```

I want to retrieve all employees (If found).

I tried to access them using:

1. `$employees->children()` [Empty Array]
2. `$employees->rows` [Empty Array]
3. `$employees->row` [Empty Array]
4. `$employees->xpath('//rows')` [Empty Array]
5. `$employees->xpath('//row')` [Empty Array]
6. `$employees->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'); $employees->xpath('//x:row')` [Empty Array]

`var_dump($employees->getName()); //returns "v"`

`var_dump($employees->getNamespaces()); //returns NULL`

`var_dump($employees);` **Returns:**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(xxx) "
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "Articles_Schema.xsd" >
        <row id="1">
            <EmployeeID>
                <![CDATA[123]]>
            </EmployeeID>
            <EmplopyeeName>
                <![CDATA[John Doe]]>
            </EmplopyeeName>
        </row>
        <row id="2">
           <EmployeeID>
                <![CDATA[456]]>
            </EmployeeID>
            <EmplopyeeName>
                <![CDATA[Jack Mill]]>
            </EmplopyeeName>
        </row>
    </rows>"
}
```

Can someone point out what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$employees =<<< EMP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "Articles_Schema.xsd" >
    <row id="1">
        <EmployeeID>
            <![CDATA[123]]>
        </EmployeeID>
        <EmplopyeeName>
            <![CDATA[John Doe]]>
        </EmplopyeeName>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
       <EmployeeID>
            <![CDATA[456]]>
        </EmployeeID>
        <EmplopyeeName>
            <![CDATA[Jack Mill]]>
        </EmplopyeeName>
    </row>
</rows>
EMP;

$employees = simplexml_load_string($employees);
foreach($employees->row as $row)
{
   print((string) $row->EmployeeID);
   print((string) $row->EmplopyeeName);
}
```

Something to try for your case:

```
$employeeXml = simplexml_load_string((string) $employees);
foreach($employeeXml->row as $row)
{
   print((string) $row->EmployeeID);
   print((string) $row->EmplopyeeName);
}
```

Comment: In my case: `var_dump($employees->row); //returns object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (0) { }`

Comment: Employees is originally returned from an `API Response` ===> `$employees = simplexml_load_string($response)->c->q[1]['v'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this as

```
$xml = <<< EMP
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rows xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "Articles_Schema.xsd" >
<row id="1">
    <EmployeeID>
        <![CDATA[123]]>
    </EmployeeID>
    <EmplopyeeName>
        <![CDATA[John Doe]]>
    </EmplopyeeName>
</row>
 <row id="2">
   <EmployeeID>
        <![CDATA[456]]>
    </EmployeeID>
    <EmplopyeeName>
        <![CDATA[Jack Mill]]>
    </EmplopyeeName>
 </row>
</rows>
EMP;
$xmlToArray = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml,null,LIBXML_NOCDATA)),true);
foreach($xmlToArray['row'] as $row){
 echo trim($row['EmployeeID']).'---'.trim($row['EmplopyeeName']);
}
```

[DEMO LINK](https://3v4l.org/ZTUCm)